# Merging parts of two dictionaries to create a new one

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I wanted to know how I can merge two dictionaries to create a new one. Suppose I have two dictionaries:

```
    a = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb', 'cc' : 'ccc'}
    b = {'aa' : '111', 'bb' : '222', 'dd' : '444', 'ee' : '555'}
```

I want to create a third dictionary, using the keys that are included in both a and b, but I want the values to be from dict a. So it would look like this:

```
   c = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb'}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I tried:

        c = b.copy()
        c.update(a)

But that includes all the k, v from both dictionaries, although it does change the values to that from dict a, where the keys are the same. This is the closest I've gotten.

Answer (score 2):

For python2 just use [dict.viewkeys](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to find the intersection of the the dict keys:

**dictview & other**

> Return the intersection of the dictview and the other object as a new set.

```
a = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb', 'cc' : 'ccc'}
b = {'aa' : '111', 'bb' : '222', 'dd' : '444', 'ee' : '555'}

print({k:a[k] for k in a.viewkeys() & b})
{'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```

For python3 just use .keys which returns a dictview object:

```
a = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb', 'cc' : 'ccc'}
b = {'aa' : '111', 'bb' : '222', 'dd' : '444', 'ee' : '555'}

print({k: a[k] for k in a.keys() & b})

{'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```

Comment: @zombs07, yep, it definitely works and using a dict comp is more efficeint than a for loop

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x , I would get `dict.keys()` and do `&` (intersection) on them, to get the common keys and then take value from `a` . Example -

```
a = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb', 'cc' : 'ccc'}
b = {'aa' : '111', 'bb' : '222', 'dd' : '444', 'ee' : '555'}
c = {}
for k in (a.keys() & b.keys()):
    c[k] = a[k]
```

Dictionary comprehension method -

```
c = {k:a[k] for k in (a.keys() & b.keys())}
```

For Python 2.7 , you can use `dict.viewkeys()` instead of `dict.keys()` method.

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> a = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb', 'cc' : 'ccc'}
>>> b = {'aa' : '111', 'bb' : '222', 'dd' : '444', 'ee' : '555'}
>>> c = {}
>>> for k in (a.keys() & b.keys()):
...     c[k] = a[k]
...
>>> c
{'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all the keys unique and you won't have the issue of the new dictionary updating the keys from dictionary a to dictionary b. You have to make all the keys unique but if not then look at the code below where I am adding a 1 to the key name to make it unique.

```
a = {'aa' : 'aaa', 'bb' : 'bbb', 'cc' : 'ccc'}
b = {'aa' : '111', 'bb' : '222', 'dd' : '444', 'ee' : '555'}

c = a.copy()

count = 0
for k, v in b.items():
    if a.has_key(k):
        while True:
            count += 1
            if c.has_key(k+str(count)):
                pass
            else:
                c[k+str(count)]=v
                count = 0
                break
    else:
        c[k]=v

print c

{'aa': 'aaa', 'bb': 'bbb', 'cc': 'ccc', 'dd': '444', 'ee': '555', 'aa1': '111', 'bb1': '222'}
```